# Calcular el valor (ASCII) de cada palabra(suma del valor de las letras) de una frase dentro de un array

Tags: java, array, ascii

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que se trata de calcular el valor de cada palabra de una frase que me introduce el usuario. Quería saber si podríais ayudarme a saber cómo hacerlo, gracias!
Lo que quiero hacer es calcular el valor de una palabra, o lo mismo, calcular la suma de cada letra en ascii.

Me he echo esto  pero no sé si estoy empezando la serpiente por el cascabel o está todo mal, pero sé que me falta lo que estoy pidiendo de calcular el valor de una palabra, o lo mismo, calcular la suma de cada letra en ascii.

```
public class ejercicio6 {

    char[] pal;    
    Paraula p = new Paraula(); //Clase que me define una palabra
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static char[] frase = null;
    private static int indice;

    LT lt = new LT(); //Clase para poder leer char, lineas, reales y enteros

    public void inicio(){ 
        int n = 0;
        String frase = new String(); //String donde metemos la frase
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { //Main donde inicializamos el juego
        ejercicio6 at = new ejercicio6();
        at.inicio();
    }

    public static char leerCarTeclado() { //esta clase sirve para leer del teclado
        char res = '.';
        if (frase != null) {
            res = frase[indice++];
        }
        return 0;
    }

        public int ContarPesoPalabra() {
        String aux;
        aux = new LT().llegirLinia(); //Lee el string
        pal = aux.toCharArray(); //Convierte la cadena en un array de chars
        int S = 0; //Contador de la suma de lo que vale cada letra en ASCII
        int n; //Numero con el que tiene que ser más grande la suma de la palabra
        n = scn.nextInt(); //Leemos el numero que nos entra el usuario
        if (S != '.') { //Si al recorrer el Array no encontramos un . seguimos
            for (int i = 0; i < pal.length; i++) { //lee todo el array
                S = S + pal[i]; //Suma el contador
                if (S >= n && S != espai) { //Si la suma de la palabra en ASCII o hay espacio, 
                                            //no sigas, si no es asi, imprime la palabra
                    System.out.println(S);
                }

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Soy nuevo en esto, y no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien.

Comment: A que le llamas peso?

Comment: A lo que pesa el conjunto de letras en su codigo ascii.
Por ejemplo: Hola
h = 23

Comment: H no es lo mismo que h en tabla ascii. Pero supongamos que la palabra es hola, como calculas su peso? Como lo haces en una hoja de papel?

Comment: Lo siento, iba a decir que quiero calcular el peso de una palabra, o lo mismo, calcular la suma de cada letra en ascii

Comment: Ahora edita la preguna y vuelve a formularla explicando esto último. También incluye hasta donde llegasta haciendo el programa. Y puntualmente cual es el paso que no estás pudiendo resolver. Esto debería mejorar la votación negativa y conseguir que te ayuden.

Comment: Vaya, gracias por el feedback Juan!

Comment: Este codigo es muy confuso. Mas alla de que no entiendo que es cada variable, tampoco entiendo que trata de hacer esa funcion.. si S es un entero, como lo comparas con un char? que es LT? que es Llegarlinia? por favor, mira [mcve], y explica tu codigo.

Comment: Graicas por el link, lo he echo de nuevo y comentado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es sumar el valor ASCII de las letras de una cadena:

```
    String cadena = "¡Bienvenido a la comunidad!"; //simple variable para probar
    int contador = 0; //esta variable contará la suma del valor ASCII de cada letra
    for (int i=0; i < cadena.length(); i++){
        contador = contador + cadena.codePointAt(i); 
    }
    System.out.println(contador);
```

> El método `.codePointAt()` devuelve el código ASCII de un carácter en
>   concreto. El carácter será el que coincida con el índice que se pasa
>   como parámetro al método.

También puedes utilizar la siguiente forma:

```
(int)cadena.charAt(i);
```

> Dado que `charAt` devuelve el caracter en la posición que coincida con
>   el índice, al indicar que hay que tratar el valor como `(int)` /integer/
>   el valor es convertido a ASCII.

En el caso de que sea un arrays de palabras en las que no hay espacios entre las palabras(si hay espacios contará el valor ASCII del espacio):

```
String[] array = {"¡", "Bienvenido", "a", "la", "comunidad", "!"};
int contador;
for(int j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
    contador=0;
    for (int i=0; i < array[j].length(); i++){
        contador = contador + (int)array[j].charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(array[j]+" en ASCII el valor es: "+contador);
}
```

En caso de que puedan haber espacios y no los quieras contar has de poner un if dentro del bucle:

```
for (int i=0; i < array[j].length(); i++){
    if(array[j].charAt(i)!=" "){ //si no es un espacio sumara su valor ASCII
        contador = contador + (int)array[j].charAt(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis. Lo  hice de una manera diferente utilizando una clase Palabra  con métodos de saltar_espacio y demás. Tengo curiosidad de ver como lo haría con tu ayuda así que lo voy a probar ya que es un método más "al palo".

Comment: @Pedro Me ha gustado eso de método "**al Palo**" jajajaja. Y espero haberte ayudado. :)