# ¿Como leer palabra por palabra de un Array?

Tags: java, array, ascii, contador

Lo que estoy mirando de hacer es un contador que me sume el valor de cada palabra en su código ASCI. Por ejemplo: Hola ( H = 45, o = 56, l = -45, a = 23. Valor Total = 79 ).

Este es el código de mi Contador:

public class Contador {

```
public static final char espacio = ' ';
char[] pal; //Definim l'array paraula
Paraula p = new Paraula();

public int ContarPes() {
    String S; //Creamos el String para leer desde teclado
    S = new LT().llegirLinia(); //Leemos todo el string
    pal = S.toCharArray(); //Pasamos el String S a Array
    int PesPal = 0; //Ponemos el contador a 0 , el cual dice qué pesa cada palabra

    for (int i = 0; i < pal.length; i++) {
        PesPal = PesPal + pal[i];
    }
    return PesPal;
}
```

}

Mi problema reside en saber cuando ya ha leído una palabr, cómo me puede pasar a la siguiente. Y al final que me imprima la suma de cada palabra por pantalla.

EDIT: Solo puedo emplear el String para entrada o salida.

Comment: en que se diferencia esta pregunta de la que hiciste ayer? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/221901/324

Comment: En que lo he vuelto a rehacer todo y lo tengo echo con otro método y estructura. De tal manera que así me haga el calculo del peso de diferente manera

Comment: ok. pero asi no funciona el sitio. Ve a tu pregunta original, a la que todos le pusimos tiempo para ayudarte, y modificala. Si haces una nueva, que para colmo es igual a la anterior, todo el trabajo en ella se pierde.

Comment: y elimina esta pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

En la misma clase donde tienes tu main, creas un metodo para usarlo posteriormente:

Ejm:

```
 public void pesoTexto(String texto){
    char [] letras = texto.toCharArray();
    int total = 0;

    for(char elemento : letras){
        total += elemento;
    }

    System.out.println("Analisis: "+texto+" = peso:"+total);
}
```

Luego lo instancias para usarlo.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Respuestas res = new Respuestas();

    String[] palabras = new String[]{"carro","avion","hielo"};
    for(String texto : palabras) res.pesoTexto(texto);
  }
```