# Al imprimir sin castear un int, ¿el número en pantalla es el valor ASCII o byte del caracter?

Tags: java

Tengo este código de ejemplo:

```
package tests;

import java.io.IOException;

public class pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int c; // byte de entrada como entero
        int contador=0;
        //Se lee hasta encontrar el fin de línea
        
        while ((c=System.in.read())!= '\n') {
            contador++;
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
        System.out.println();//Se escribe el fin de línea
        System.err.println("Contados "+contador+" bytes en total");
        
    }

}
```

Lo que no entiendo es, cuando quitas el `(char) c`, pones solo la variable `c` y le escribes la letra "H", te da un número, ¿ese número qué es? ¿su número en ASCII o en byte?

Comment: Por favor, leé [ask]. Fijate cómo cambia el sentido de la pregunta cuando se le coloca un título _relevante_.

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta en sí, es cuestión de buscar... [Buscá qué hace el casteo de `int` a `char`](https://search.brave.com/search?q=cast+int+char+java) (usá el motor de búsqueda de tu preferencia).

Comment: Supongo que por byte te refieres a binario. Para pasar de texto a binario se usa una conversión (enconding: ASCII, unicode, windows-128, etc). Ahora bien, hasta donde entiendo, todos los encoding más usados, usan como base el ASCII, entonces si es ¿ASCII o binario? la verdad es que son ambos

Comment: como c es un int inmediatamente hace el casteo de 'H' el cual te devolvera 72 su valor en tabla ASCII ,te preguntaras me sale 7213 y es por que estas usando print y el 13  seria por que al pulsar la tecla ENTER se genera un carácter especial llamado "retorno de carro". cuyo valor en la tablas ASCII,  acertaste es 13 ;)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Calcular el valor (ASCII) de cada palabra(suma del valor de las letras) de una frase dentro de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221901/calcular-el-valor-ascii-de-cada-palabrasuma-del-valor-de-las-letras-de-una-f)